# Help reducing a set of features

Tags: clustering, dataset

I am trying to do some clustering. I have a dataset that is very
sparse - with the majority of features only occurring in a single vector.

Here is a list of our features:
https://gist.github.com/scrooloose/5963725dc88e5d15d74dcae522bebf82

I am looking for any suggestions/hints/pointers as to how we can merge some of
these isolated features together. This should hopefully make my clustering
experiments more successful.

For example, from a manual inspection of the data, I can see this group of
features that could be all merged into a feature like "health" or perhaps
"mental health" + "general health" or similar.

```
618: Mental Health Research
619: Mental disorder
1616: mental health
1617: mental illness
1618: men’s health
410: Genital wart
402: Genomic Medicine
476: Hygiene
```

Another example is this set of features that could be merged into something
like "education":

```
536: Kiir Primary School
591: Makonzi Boarding School
609: Mathematics
670: New York University
300: Education
301: Educational psychology
349: Female education
```

Any thoughts would be very welcome, thanks :)

Side note: These features are keywords as returned from alchemy
(http://www.alchemyapi.com/). Resulting from keyword searches for a set of
URLS. The intention is to cluster the URLs (and hence they companies they
represent) by these keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to cluster urls by using the keywords extracted as features. As these features are really sparse, you can try to use dimensionality reductions methods to help you.

One way is to treat each URL keywords as a document. Then you can use document embeddings algorithms such as [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) or [doc2vec](https://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/) that learn denser representations of your documents.

If you want to group keywords, you can try to use word embeddings methods that learn representations of words. Using this you can then measure the similarity between words and groups of words.
An example is the well-known [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec). Recent methods like [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) can be alternative that take the morphology into account.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, I will investigate these methods at work this week. I'm quite new to this whole area of machine learning / data science. It's all a bit overwhelming - so I appreciate the pointers :-)

Comment: @scrooloose glad it's helpful!